# iOS 11 - Do not allow recording of app

Tags: ios, ios11, replaykit, anti-piracy, rpscreenrecorder

Apple announced system-level screen recording to be a feature of iOS 11. This is great for gaming and probably many other use cases, but not good for content apps such as Netflix, YouTube, Spotify, etc.

Will it be possible for developers to not allow system-level screen recording of their apps?

At about 15 minutes into [this demonstration during WWDC 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/606/), we find out that your application will be notified via RPScreenRecorderDelegate in the event that a user interrupts an in-app screen recording with a system-level screen-recording.

This is good, but they do not mention being notified at all if screen-recording begins in the case that your app isn't already performing an in-app screen capture.

Earlier in the demonstration they mention that you application contains a shared instance of the RPScreenRecorder. Does anyone know if the system also uses this instance and whether its [isAvailable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder/1620992-isavailable) property will be set to `false` in the event that a user is performing a system-level screen recording?

I would like to know if Apple has any type of support for disabling this feature in your app, or if there is some way I can check if the user is recording in order to adjust the appearance of the app so that licensed content cannot be pirated and redistributed by users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to [UIScreen isCaptured](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2921651-iscaptured)

Comment: Does it really work? Isn’t it called for airplay too?